# How to obtain the msg.sender in truffle console?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-console

Here is my code snippet to return the msg.sender:

```
function showSender() public view returns (address)  
{  
    return (msg.sender);  
}
```

But when I try to call this function using this:

```
Coin.deployed().then(function(instance) { return instance.showSender.call();});
```

Then there is an error showing:

```
Error: Invalid number of parameters for "showSender". Got 0 expected 2!
at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/execute.js:128:1)
at Object._createTxObject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:699:1)
at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/~/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:32:1)
```

The function showSender does not have any parameter, then why is the error showing up. Someone please give a solution.

Comment: Change `showSender` to `showSender()`.

Comment: Then I have to remove the .call() right?? - @goodvibration

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: It's still showing up the same error :( - @goodvibration

Comment: You're probably using a different ABI or something (probably because you forgot to recompile).

Comment: What should I do then? Cos when I compiled it again, it says "Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile."- @goodvibration

Comment: This is probably some weird Truffle quirk. Try removing your `build` directory and try compiling and running your code again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!!! Thanks a lot @IvanAndrusenko